# webpack plugin withWeb (by nx) leads to "module is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I´m using the [withWeb webpack plugin](https://nx.dev/packages/webpack/documents/webpack-plugins#withweb) from `nx` to build a typescript file into javascript together with a html and a css file:

```
const { composePlugins, withNx, withWeb } = require('@nx/webpack');

module.exports = composePlugins(
  withNx(),
  withWeb({
    index: 'apps/myApp/src/index.html',
    styles: ['apps/myApp/src/index.css'],
  }),
  (config) => ({
    ...config,
  })
);
```

In the resulting html the javascript is imported as modules:

```
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="styles.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

In the browser I then get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`.

I honestly don´t need the imported javascript to be modules or even be multiple files. Can I disable the creation of modules? Is there an easier way to create a dist javascript, html and css from a src ts, html and css with webpack?